# OR'ed backreferences in regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, backreference

Could someone please explain how this regular expression is supposed to work:

```
^(a)|\1$
```

?

I intepret it as:

*1. start of string,

followed by:

*2. either:

*2a. an `a`,

or:

*2b. the previously matched `(a)` group,

followed by:

*3. end of string

But then, 2b is an impossibility, because there is no previously matched `(a)` group if 2b is chosen over 2a. So, the interpretation is equivalent to:

*1. start of string,

followed by:

*2. an `a`,

followed by:

*3. end of string

In other words, that regular expression is equivalent to just: `^a$` (One could just as well say that the OR'ed backreference is nonsensical.)

But then, in Python I get:

```
>>> import re

>>> re.findall(r'^a$', r'aa')
[] # as expected

>>> re.findall(r'^(a)|\1$', r'a')
['a'] # as expected

>>> re.findall(r'^(a)|\1$', r'aa')
['a'] # NOT as expected
```

How can `aa` possibly match `^(a)|\1$` ?

Comment: I'm afraid `^(a)|\1$` means `(?:^(a))|(?:\1$)`, not `^(?:(a)|\1)$`. The behavior is perfectly consistent.

Comment: Generally, if I find my regex getting this complicated, I do something else. What are you trying to accomplish with this regex? It's not the right tool for every job.

Comment: @Jan: Yes, you are right. I got caught by operators precedence... Thanks.

Comment: @jpmc26: "Tell us what you need, we'll explain why you don't need it."

Comment: @user1387866 I suppose. I just see tons of questions related to back referencing with regex, which suggests to me that it's markedly complicated to use. The fact it's complicated suggests to me that there are probably better ways of dealing with those cases, and even once you make it work, it's difficult to maintain because of the complexity. Hence why I avoid it, and hence why I thought it might be useful to consider other avenues.

Comment: @user1387866: ++thanks for that quote.  I've needed it *many* times!

Comment: @jpmc You can't say backref is complicated. **1)** The pattern exposed by OP is particular, hence it may confuse at first glance. But it's rapidly clear that the whole pattern never matches from start to beginning because of the OR symbol in it. The problem of the OP was that he persuaded himself that ``^(a)|\1$`` matches ``aa``. It doesn't match ``aa``, it matches **in** ``aa``. This pattern is particular because the second part ``\1$`` will never matches, that's right.

Comment: **2)** The apparent complication of backref in general is due to the complication of the natural process to obtain the complicated result. Try to execute at hand a research, you'll see it requires focusing one's mind ! The regexes allow to execute this process rapidly and if the research is complicated, the regex tool seems complex, but we should on contrary be happy that such a tool is able to manage complicated researches. The complication is not their fault.

Comment: That's right there's also a kind of difficulty to keep one's way in the forest of parens delimiting groups, sometimes. Some people like the required meticulosity to craft a regex and backrefs, others don't. And some people have no complicated research to do that would oblige them to use regex and backrefs. But regexes are not complicated _per se_

Comment: @eyquem It's just an opinion that's open to being changed. I don't like backrefs because they extend regular expressions beyond their original purpose of analyzing regular languages. I feel like a parser tends to be a superior tool for doing that, and I tend to look at complicated expressions in terms of maintainability. 6 months to a year down the road, I'm not likely to remember off-hand how it works when I have to work on that code again. You and the OP are free to disagree. Either way, it can still be the right tool; there just needs to be a good reason. (And no one has to tell me.)

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a case of unreachable regex code:

In principal, this matches either a single `a` at the beginning of a line, or a single `a` at the end of a line if and only if a single `a` at the begining of the line has already been matched. However, since matching a single `a` at the begining of the line means the match is already done, the second part of the regex will never be reached and just the first `a` will always be returned.

I'm guessing you have a more complicated group instead of just "a" specifically, so here's one that matches the phrase `a`, a second `a` (optional), and then the end of the line: `^(a)\1?$`

That means "Match `a` at the begining of the line, and then allow another foo if it's there, and then the end of the string, where `a` can be any regex pattern. If `a` really is just the letter "a", then `^aa?$` is a simpler alternative.

If you just want to match any whole line starting with or ending with `a`, then `^(a.*|.*a)$` would work, or `^(a[^\n]*|[^\n]*a)$` if using single-line mode, simplified as `^(a.*?|.*?a)$` for regex flavors supporting the `*?` operator. Unfortunately, in this case, the pattern for `a` must be written both at the beginning and end of the overall pattern, as back-references won't do the trick. If `a` is a pattern with the `|` operator, then surround it in parentheses like `^((a).*|.*(a))$`.